# Finding the maxima without second derivative test

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization, continuity

How can I verify that a critical point is a maximum without using the second derivative test?

Here is the specific situation.

There is a function $f(x)\ge 0$ and $x\ge 0$ as they are both distances. Now I found that 
$$
\frac {df}{dx}=\frac {2}{(1+\frac{2^2}{x^2})x^2}-\frac{8}{(1+\frac{8^2}{x^2}) x^2}
$$
and when $\frac {df}{dx}=0, x=\pm 4$, but clearly cannot be $-4$. Now I must show that $x=4$ maximizes $f(x)$ without using the second derivative test.

Comment: The edit of Subhadeep Dey can´t be right, because $f'(\pm 4) \neq 0$. minusatwelth please improve the question by yourself.

Comment: The original post says $df/dx=(2)/((1+(2)^2/x^2) x^2)-(8)/((1+(8)^2/x^2) x^2)$

Comment: Maybe $ df/dx=\dfrac{(2/x^2)}{1+(2/x)^2} -  \dfrac{(8/x^2)}{1+(8/x)^2}  ? $ OP to clarify..

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%29%2F%28%281%2B%282%29^2%2Fx^2%29+x^2%29-%288%29%2F%28%281%2B%288%29^2%2Fx^2%29+x^2%29%3D0

Comment: Analyze the derivative before and after that point.

Comment: wolfram is giving me those solutions

Comment: The equation should be correct now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying the derivative you get
$$
f'(x)=\frac{6(16-x^2)}{(x^2+4)(x^2+64)}=\frac{6(4-x)(4+x)}{(x^2+4)(x^2+64)}.
$$
Now you see that

- for $0\le x<4$: $f'(x)>0$ $\Rightarrow$ the function *increases*,
- for $x>4$: $f'(x)<0$ $\Rightarrow$ the function *decreases*.

Hence, $x=4$ is the maximum point.

Comment: i plotted the graph and it doesn't look increasing on $0<x<4$ see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%29%2F%28%281%2B%282%29^2%2Fx^2%29+x^2%29-%288%29%2F%28%281%2B%288%29^2%2Fx^2%29+x^2%29%3D0

Comment: @minusatwelfth The link is broken. What is your function? The derivative you gave is the derivative of $\arctan(8/x)-\arctan(2/x)$ and it *is* increasing for $0\le x\le 4$ ([look](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e4a06bgbsks))

Comment: oh ok, how can i show it won't increase again?

Comment: @minusatwelfth After $x=4$ the derivative is negative, so the function decreases. It means that the functions goes down all the way when x goes to infinity so it cannot become larger then $f(4)$, since for that it would need to grow again, but it was not. To look at the derivative sign and calculate the monotonicity intervals is much more efficient way to study max/min than the second derivative (which gives  only *local* extremum).